# Filter dataframe on not null rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame from this form:

```
In [122]: df=pd.DataFrame({"A":["1,2,3","4,5,6",np.nan,"8"],"B":[6,7,8,9]})

In [123]: df
Out[123]:
       A  B
0  1,2,3  6
1  4,5,6  7
2    NaN  8
3      8  9
```

I want to filter the lines in B where the list in A contain specific value, for example "4".

I tried using this syntax:

```
df["B"][["4" in a for a in df["A"].str.split(',')]]
```

But I get `TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable` because of the `NaN` in one of the lines. So I tried this syntax-

```
df["B"][["4" in a for a in df["A"].str.split(',') if pd.notnull(a)]]
```

But I get `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Any idea how can I make it work? I tried few ideas but none of them worked, and I don't really know why this syntax is wrong.

Expected output- `7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pandas alternative:

```
s = df.loc[df["A"].str.split(',', expand=True).eq('4').any(axis=1), 'B']
print (s)
1    7
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

**Explanation**:

Create DataFrame by parameter `expand=True` in [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
print (df["A"].str.split(',', expand=True))
     0     1     2
0    1     2     3
1    4     5     6
2  NaN   NaN   NaN
3    8  None  None
```

Comapre by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) (`==`):

```
print (df["A"].str.split(',', expand=True).eq('4'))
       0      1      2
0  False  False  False
1   True  False  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

check if at least one `True` per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df["A"].str.split(',', expand=True).eq('4').any(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

And last filter by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Your solution should be changed with `if-else` and `isinstance`:

```
mask = ["4" in a if isinstance(a, list) else False for a in df["A"].str.split(',')]

s = df.loc[mask, 'B']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":["14,2,3","4,5,6",np.nan,"8"],"B":[6,7,8,9]})
df[df['A'].str.contains(r'\b4\b', na=False)]
```

Would give you:

```
    A       B
1   4,5,6   7
```

Then you can select only the column `B`.

```
df[df['A'].str.contains(r'\b4\b', na=False)]['B']

# Output:
1    7
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

**EDIT:**

Instead of using `.contains('4')` you should use `.contains(r'\b4\b')`. In order to avoid picking up 14 or any other number that contains 4